# XAMPP/Chrome net::ERR_CERT_INVALID on VALID Certificate Chain

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, apache, chrome, xampp

I have set up my own Root CA and Intermediate CAs for my local sites (virtual sites). I also have installed them to trusted certificates in my computer and also the intermediate CAs on their own folder in the cert market of my computer.

However, when I open my website in a browser it finds my certificate invalid. **What could be the fix to this?** Please consider pictures below.

I use Yandex Browser (almost the same as Chrome Browser)

[image]

Comment: What does a current version of vanilla Chrome report? (Press `F12` and then choose the `Security` tab.)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same situation today: self-signed CA (registered as trustworthy CA) and server certificate signed by that CA.

- **Firefox** and **Edge** accepted the certificate
- **Java** accepted it as well (JAX-RS request with CA in truststore)
- but **Chrome rejected** it with `ERR_CERT_INVALID`.

The CA and server certificate both used **EC-256** key material.

When I recreated the CA and server certificate, using **RSA-2048** keys instead of Elliptic Curves, the certificate chain was **accepted by Chrome**.

Seems to be an ECC issue with Chrome and other Chrome based user agents (such as Postman, which also wouldn't connect when using ECC keys).